# How to get the SUM total value to appear in cell vs the formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, keyboard-shortcuts

So I have created a spreadsheet to add cells `=SUM(B2:B20)` ... When I hit enter the sum value should be in the cell I created the formula but instead, I have just the formula after hitting enter.  How can I get the actual Sum total?

Answer (score 0):

- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`` ` ``</kbd>** to trigger result overview

  [image: 0]
- to turn this:

  [image: 0]
- into this:

  [image: 0]
- and vice versa